# How to import second workbook, get its sheet and paste it to my current sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a complex solution to reading sheets from existing workbooks in chosen directory and appending to my existing single sheet in my main workbook. Location of input files could be changed, so I think it's better to use OpenFile methods and get files paths automatically.

The case is, that I have e.g. 500 downloaded workbooks from statistical office, every one of them includes only one sheet, and structure of the data is always the same. The same columns, the same types of data inside. Generally one subject of my research.

I found this example (https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/copy-paste-another-workbook/ - "Pasting Below the Last Cell") but I don't know how to change the source of location.

My current code is:

```
Sub openAndCopyData()

    Dim importedFile As Variant

    importedFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xlsx*;")

    If importedFile <> False Then
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=importedFile
    End If

    Dim sheetToCopy As Worksheet
    Dim sheetToPaste As Worksheet
    Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
    Dim lDestLastRow As Long

    Set sheetToCopy = importedFile.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sheetToPaste = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    lCopyLastRow = sheetToCopy.Cells(sheetToCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lDestLastRow = sheetToPaste.Cells(sheetToPaste.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

    sheetToCopy.Range("A2:D" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
    sheetToPaste.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)


End Sub
```

I wish to get appended data inside my main sheet after import every one of my files, because of its parallel structure. If it will works, I will introduce filter methods and other improvements.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you want to be able to specify a folder and then you want to loop through all files in that folder, open each one in Excel, copy the data, close it and then move on to the next file, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. If this could work I will prepare some code to filter data before copy to main sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the objective of your question is to loop through all the selected files for Copying then may try

```
Sub openAndCopyData()
    Dim importedFile As Variant
    'importedFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files,*.xlsx*;")
    importedFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files,*.xlsx*;", 1, _
"Select Files to Copy", "Get Data from Files", True)

    If TypeName(importedFile) = "Boolean" And Not (IsArray(importedFile)) Then Exit Sub

    Dim sheetToCopy As Worksheet
    Dim sheetToPaste As Worksheet
    Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
    Dim lDestLastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long


    For i = 1 To UBound(importedFile)
    Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(importedFile(i))
    Set sheetToCopy = Wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sheetToPaste = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lCopyLastRow = sheetToCopy.Cells(sheetToCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lDestLastRow = sheetToPaste.Cells(sheetToPaste.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    sheetToCopy.Range("A2:D" & lCopyLastRow).Copy _
    sheetToPaste.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)
    Wb.Close False
    Next
End Sub
```

code is tested with makeshift data files.

Comment: You made my day